# Why does tomcat's application not work without ending slash?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have tomcat7 on Debian 8.
Why my application works with this link

```
http://x.x.x.x:8080/test/
```

and doesn't work with this link?

```
http://x.x.x.x:8080/test
```

How make it works?

Comment: First: I wouldn't put an ip unless you are baiting people. What do you have in web.xml? Are you using web.xml? Where are you setting the paths?

Comment: Thanks, I'm tired and I forget about the ip:) I don't use .xml, I just have index.html

Comment: It is a path issue, Look in the java classes where you have the path annotations and check why the cap occurs

Comment: But I have only one html file at this project. There is no java.

Comment: check then tomcat's config where the default's path handlers are defined. It is a path issue

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work *because* you haven't provided a `web.xml` for an application called `test` which contains an `index.html` file.

Tomcat isn't a general-purpose HTTP server. Are you looking for Apache HTTPD?

Comment: Thanks. I'm just a newbie in tomcat and I use it for java. How cat i fix this issue with the web.xml?